# How to print a message using QThread in PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am new to threading in pyqt5. I was able to make a worker thread to run my long-running program in it in order to avoid freezing of the program. In my simple program, after creating worker thread, a function with name `runInThread` starts to count from 0 to 50.
Now my problem is that during the program if the current number which is shown with `c` variable is equal to 20 or if it is equal to 30, just do a simple print in a QLabel which its name is `time1` and its initial text is `number` in the code below. I know there is a way to write my `runInThread` function inside the `run()` function in `Worker` class and then use `self.progress.emit(i + 1)` inside it, but my real program includes so many function in the main class and modifying them is really hard.

```
import sys
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication,QLabel,QMainWindow,QPushButton,QVBoxLayout,QWidget,)


class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        self.N = Window()
        self.N.runInThread()
        
        self.finished.emit()
#***************************************************************
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.clicksCount = 0
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Freezing GUI")
        self.resize(300, 150)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        # Create and connect widgets
        self.clicksLabel = QLabel("Counting: 0 clicks", self)
        self.clicksLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.stepLabel = QLabel("Long-Running Step: 0")
        self.stepLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.countBtn = QPushButton("Click me!", self)
        self.countBtn.clicked.connect(self.countClicks)
        self.longRunningBtn = QPushButton("Long-Running Task!", self)
        self.longRunningBtn.clicked.connect(self.runLongTask)
        self.time1 = QLabel("number",self)
        self.time1.move(10,90)
        # Set the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.clicksLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.countBtn)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.stepLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.longRunningBtn)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
#****************************************************************
    def countClicks(self):
        self.clicksCount += 1
        self.clicksLabel.setText(f"Counting: {self.clicksCount} clicks")

    def reportProgress(self, n):
        self.stepLabel.setText(f"Long-Running Step: {n}")


    def runInThread(self):

        c=0
        for i in range(50):
            c += 1
            sleep(1)


    def runLongTask(self):
        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker()
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.run)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        # Step 6: Start the thread
        self.thread.start()

        # Final resets
        self.longRunningBtn.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.longRunningBtn.setEnabled(True))
        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.stepLabel.setText("Long-Running Step: 0"))

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

I really appreciate answers which solves the problem

Comment: Qt does not support GUI operations of any kind outside the main thread. Creating a `Window` in the worker thread is not thread-safe and will eventually result in a crash. Just pass a reference to the long-running function along with any args / kwargs to `Worker.__init__`, and store them as attributes; then call the function inside `run`. *Do not attempt to directly update any widgets from the worker thread*. Always use custom signals to send notifications to the main thread, and update widgets in slots connected to those signals.